# Converting a bean path to a simple string property in Ext GWT grid

Tags: gwt, binding, gxt

I am working on an Ext GWT 3 (beta) application.

I am trying to display a simple value of a dependent bean in a `Grid`.

My data beans look like this:

```
public class MyBean {
    private String content;

    private MyOtherBean otherBean;

    // getters and setters here...
}


public class MyOtherBean {
    private String otherBeanContent;

    // getter and setter here...
}
```

The `PropertyAccess` looks like this:

```
interface MyBeanProperties extends PropertyAccess<MyBean> {

    ModelKeyProvider<MyBean> key();

    ValueProvider<MyBean, String> content();

    ValueProvider<MyBean, MyOtherBean> otherBean();
}
```

With the corresponding `ColumnConfiguration`, my grid now displays one column with `content` of `MyBean` and one column with `MyOtherBean`'s `toString()`.

But I want to display `MyOtherBean.otherBeanContent` instead (without changing `MyOtherBean`'s `toString()`).

I think I need some kind of value converter and register it for the column? Or am I taking the wrong approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
columnConfig.setCell(new PropertyDisplayCell<MyOtherBean>(new PropertyEditor<MyOtherBean>() {

        @Override
        public MyOtherBean parse(CharSequence text) throws ParseException {
            return otherBean.setOtherBeanContentFromText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public String render(MyOtherBean otherBean) {
            return otherBean == null ? "" : otherBean.getOtherBeanContent();
        }
    }));
```